# Use unicode text in tex document

Tags: unicode

I try below sample but can not pass compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
├── version.txt
└── visible_windows.zip
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4 └── visible_
                windows.zip
? x
```

content is output of tree command from linux.

Comment: Underscore can be used in regular text, but you have to use a relevant TeX format (no LaTeX:-).

Comment: @wipet you know that's a misleading comment, it's true that in optex you only need to locally change end of line and not `_` and in latex and plain you need to change both, but to suggest that some formats can do this and some not is ....

Comment: You get ***many*** more errors with your code.

Comment: What errors and in what code means egreg?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see (at this site) that there is a lot of user mistakes concerned to the fact, that `_` is set with catcode 8. This thread is only one example of such mistakes. I know that If you will design a new format from scratch then you don't set the catcode 8 to `_` in order to avoid such user mistakes. But, of course, LaTeX must keep old principles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
├── version.txt
└── visible_windows.zip
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In OpTeX, `_` is normal character:

```
\fontfam[stix]

\obeylines
├── version.txt
└── visible_windows.zip

\bye
```

It generates, what you want.